# iOS: equivalence for migration AddressBook to Contact framework

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, cncontactstore

I'm migrating from AddressBook to Contact Framework in iOS 9, and encountered a few issues, could someone with similar experience share some opinions?

1. `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions`

Is it the same as creating a new `CNContactStore` instance?

2. `ABRecordCopyCompositeName`

What's the equivalent method in contact framework? From its documentation, it returns:

> For person records: The concatenated value of these properties:
>   Prefix, Suffix, Organization, First name, and Last name.

But I couldn't find an equivalent way of getting the same information from contact store?

3. `ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel`

Is it the same as calling `labeldValue.value.stringValue`?

Thanks!